# Wordpress page specific css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site where I added banner and sidebar filter option. But the banner shows as a conflict with filter option. If I added `margin-top:300px` then it goes down but this change applies to every page. I want to change this for the specific page only because I don't have banner on every page.

My site: http://motor.racedrivenonly.com/shop

Header image below:

[image: Site Header]

Comment: Another option might be to put that banner in above the content so you don't have to adjust styles conditionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are classes added to the body tag in WordPress. Try to determine the proper body class ad you'll be able to add the margin based on a particular page template or type of page.

Try something like this:

```
.post-type-archive-product .blog-sb-widgets {
    margin-top: 300px;
}
```